# Select window element in JQuery 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to close a modal when the user clicks anywhere outside the modal(W3C website example). However, I am using JQuery as opposed to plain JS on W3C website.
$modal is a jquery object containing the html div used to create the modal

I tried this code I saw on stackoverflow, but no success:

```
let $window = $('window', opener.document);

window.parent.$window.on('click', function(event){
    if (event.target == $modal){
        $modal.css({display:'none'});
    }
});
```

What I tried myself:

```
 let $window = $('window');
 window.on('click', function(event){
        if(event.target == $modal){
            $modal.css({display:'none'});
        }
    }
```

Mixing Plain JS with JQuery:

```
 let $window = $('window');
 window.onclick = function(event){
    if(event.target == $modal){
        $modal.css({display:'none'});
    }
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: so.... by $modal, do you mean an iframe? or... a div with content in it? An entirely new browser window?

Comment: @KevinB browser window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I dont really know what you mean about $modal but here is an example to manage a simple modal with css and jquery as you asked:

```js
 var modal = $('#myModal'),
  span = $(".close")[0],
  btn = $('#mybtn');
  $(span).on('click',function() {
   $(modal).css("display", "none");
   });
      
  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target == $(modal)[0] ) {
     $(modal).css("display", "none");
    }
   })
      
       $(btn).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(modal).css("display", "block");
   })
```

```css
/**
* modal css
**/
/* Modal fondo */
.modal {
 display: none; /* Hidden */
 position: fixed; /*mantener posicion*/
 z-index: 1; /* index top */
 padding-top: 100px; /* inicio del content modal */
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto; /* usar scroll si la pagina excede el tamanio */
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* fondo */
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /*opacidad */
}

/**
* caja modal
*/
.modal-content {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #fefefe;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid #888;
 width: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
 -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
 animation-name: animatetop;
 animation-duration: 0.4s
}


@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
 from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
 to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
 from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
 to {top:0; opacity:1}
}


.close {
 color: white;
 float: right;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
 padding: 2px 16px;
 background-color: #4a7ac9;
 color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
 padding: 2px 16px;
 background-color: #4a7ac9;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

 <!--Content-->
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <span class="close">&times;</span>
   <h2 id="consultaTecnico"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="modalForm">
   
    <p>Hello World</p>

  
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <input type="button" id="mybtn" value="show modal">
```

I guess your problem was here :

```
if(event.target == $modal)
```

Your modal was saved as the element 0 of you jquery object

Hope it helps

Comment: $modal is the jquery object containing the div used to create the modal